# How to reload a css background-image inside a directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In Angular, I have directive that loads a background-image attribute. How do I get the background image to reload on demand?

```
app.directive('profilePhotoPreview', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            uuid: "="
        },
        template: "",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('uuid', function (value) {
                console.log('profilePhotoPreview ',value);
                if (scope.uuid) {
                    scope.preview = "url('"+conf.s3 + "user_profile_photos/" + scope.uuid + ".jpg')";

                    var s={'width':'400px', 'height':'400px','background-image': scope.preview}
                    element.css(s);
                }

            })

        }
    }
});
```

In this scenario, the underlying photo has been changed (ie a new profile photo has been uploaded), but the url is the same.

I've tried setting a $watch on the uuid variable and flipping its value from null back to its old value to fool Angular into re-rendering the css, but this has no effect.

Comment: could this be a result of the browser using cached data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case browser has already cached that image. To reload it you can add '?xxxx' to image url, where 'xxxx' is a random string.

I mean you only need to change your scope.preview variable when you want to reload pic:

```
scope.preview = "url('"+conf.s3 + "user_profile_photos/" + scope.uuid + ".jpg?"+getRandomInt(0, 10000)+")";

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: This will result in all user profile images always being downloaded.

Comment: We can add '?xxxx' only when picture is updated. So by default it will be clear url finished with '.jpg'

Comment: And it is better here to use ng-style, so angular could change style itself, without jquery. That'll be clearer.